# Show that $\angle AQP = \angle PQC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, angle, homothety

Given a triangle $\triangle ABC$ whose incenter is $I$, its $A-$exincenter is $O$, the midpoint of $AC$ is $M$, $P = OM \cap BC$ and $Q = AI \cap (ABC) \neq A$. Prove that $\angle AQP = \angle PQC$.

[image]

It is easy to see that $QB= QC=QO = QI$, so I thought about the spiral similarity between $AC$ and $IO$, but it is a weird one because its centers would be either points $C$ or $A$? Anyways, I couldn't find a simple solution neither find some harmonic pencil.

the great problem seems to be that point $M$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the source of the problem?  Since I am uneducated in Geometry, if this problem is from a book, I suspect that it may be a book that I wish to buy.  Alternatively, if this problem is from a website, I will probably want to visit the website.

Comment: @user2661923 sadly, I don't have the source. A friend of mine sent me it and asked for help. I will ask him next time we meet.

Comment: I haven't solved it yet, but some thoughts: the problem is equivalent to showing that $IBQP$ is cyclic, or yet equivalently, that $IP$ and $AC$ are parallel. I also noticed that, if $R$ denotes the intersection of $IP$ and the circumcircle of $IBOC$, then $PQRC$ is also cyclic, which is again equivalent to the problem. I am not yet sure how to use that $M$ is the centre of $BC$. Perhaps you must exploit that, if $X$ denotes the intersection of $OB$ with the circumcircle of $ABC$, then $XM$ is perpendicular to $AC$. This gives the direction of $OM$. I hope these remarks will prove to be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $IP$ meet $AC$ at $X$ and let $AO$ cuts $BC$ at $A'$.

Then we have \begin{align} (A,C;X,M)&= (PA,PC;PX,PM) \\ &= (PA, PA'; PI, PO) \\ &= (A,A'; I,O) \\ &=-1
\end{align}

Since $M$ is the midpoint of $AC$ it means $X=\infty$, so $IP||AC$.

But now it is easy to see that $BQPI$ ic cyclic and by simle angle chase we get the conclusion.

Comment: If you don't mind, live it unaccepted for a while. Perhaps some new ideas people will share them with us.

Comment: Any way, what is a source of this problem?

Comment: I've done quite some high school geometry but never before have I seen the notation $(A, B; C, D)$ before; neither with sides. Could you clarify what that might mean? Is it some kind of cross ratio?

Comment: It is cross ratio @MikeDaas

Comment: I think it wouldn't hurt if some more clarification was added for the various equalities you so quickly list. Still, it looks to me like your solution makes sense. It would be nice if it can be rewritten in a way to not rely on projective geometry, but that'd be just for fun

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint: In figure CI and CD are interior and exterior bisectors of angle $ACB$. In triangle ICD,  QE is perpendicular bisector of IC and it meets the bisector of angle QDC at E. In this way :

$\angle IQE=\angle EQC$

Now all you have to do is to show that P is on QE.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the problem is still that point $M$